# How to increase the steps of scipy.stats.randint?

Tags: python, random, scipy, distribution, scipy.stats

I'm trying to generate a frozen discrete Uniform Distribution (like `stats.randint(low, high)`) but with steps higher than one, is there any way to do this with scipy ?
I think it could be something close to hyperopt's `hp.uniformint`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rv_discrete(values=(xk, pk))`  constructs a distribution with support `xk` and provabilities `pk`.

See an example in the docs:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_discrete.html

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you want to generate a uniform discrete variable with a step (eg., step=3 with low=2 and high=10 gives a universe of [2,5,8])

You can generate a different uniform variable and rescale:

```
from scipy import stats
low = 2
high = 10
step = 3
r = stats.randint(0, (high-low+1)//step)
low+r.rvs(size=10)*step
```

example output: `array([2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 8, 2, 5, 5, 2])`

Comment: Thank you, this indeed generate the required results, but it does not generate a _frozen distribution_ for later use.

Comment: Nice! (+1) . It's always refreshing to see a simple DIY solution   irrespective on if a heavy framework implements a one-liner. NB : you can use np.random.randint and avoid the scipy.stats dependency altogether.

Comment: @ev-br thanks, I also like numpy's API a lot, I often find scipy's a bit too convoluted despite its incredible number of methods ;)